# How do I add multiple rows to a Power Query Table VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with only a button for adding the additional rows required to complete. This is laborious and I know VBA can improve it, however I am new to Power Query and whether this changes the VBA Code in any way.

Any advice greatly appreciated. Thank You

```
    Sub AddRow()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: When you refresh the query, PQ should read in the Table as it exists at the time you hit the refresh button. So if you change the table structure, whether manually or by VBA, PQ should pick up the change.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hello Ron, It's more about adding the VBA code into the above to add multiple rows instead of 1x. 
The PQ is simply a concern as I am unsure if standard VBA code edit (which I could probably do myself) would affect the existing Queries. Thank You

Comment: I suggest you make the changes in your VBA code and see what happens to your query. Post back, or ask a new question, if there are issues.